How to use a GPU Buffer from UE5 as input into a CUDA kernel?
I am trying to use an UE5 GPU Buffer in a CUDA kernel (from an external library).
I have looked into the only example of the Unreal Sources located in FRivermaxInputStream.cpp but couldn't reproduce their sucessful mapping, and into the CUDA Samples SimpleD3D12.cpp.
I built a minimal project where I run a lambda on the Rendering Thread that creates an RHIBuffer and tries to map it in CUDA.
Unfortunatly, the CUDA device pointer I get from cuExternalMemoryGetMappedBuffer() throws an CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE (invalid argument) on usage.
Here is a link to the main file (and minimal project) : Github Project
I am running out of ideas on what I am missing and how I can debug it.
Once we get this to work, I plan on leaving this project public as a starter point for developers in the future.
Thanks for your help.
EDIT :
Here are the key steps of my code to map the D3D12 Buffer to CUDA (I didn't want to flood the post with code, so I posted the full file on Github).
// Create the Buffer
const EBufferUsageFlags Flags = BUF_StructuredBuffer | BUF_Shared | BUF_ShaderResource | BUF_UnorderedAccess;
FRHIBuffer* const Buffer = RHICreateBuffer(Count, Flags, Stride, ResourceState, CreateInfo);
// Get the D3D12 Resource
ID3D12Resource* const NativeD3D12Resource = GetID3D12DynamicRHI()->RHIGetResource(Buffer);

// Create the D3D12 SharedHandle
HANDLE D3D12SharedHandle;
NativeD3D12Device->CreateSharedHandle(NativeD3D12Resource, nullptr, GENERIC_ALL, nullptr, &D3D12SharedHandle);

// Import the D3D12 memory in CUDA
CUDA_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_DESC Desc{};
Desc.type = CUexternalMemoryHandleType::CU_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_D3D12_RESOURCE;
Desc.handle.win32.handle = D3D12SharedHandle;
Desc.size = GetID3D12DynamicRHI()->RHIGetResourceMemorySize(Buffer);
Desc.flags = CUDA_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_DEDICATED;
CUexternalMemory Handle;
FCUDAModule::CUDA().cuImportExternalMemory(&Handle, &Desc);

// Map the imported memory
CUdeviceptr Ptr;
FCUDAModule::CUDA().cuExternalMemoryGetMappedBuffer(&Ptr, CudaExternalMemoryHandle, &Desc);

// Use the CUDA ptr
FCUDAModule::CUDA().cuMemcpyHtoD(BufferCudaPtr, SomeCpuArray.GetData(), Count * Stride); // <---- CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE



I'm voting to close because this question is cross posted here on the Stack Overflow. Cross posting (posting the same question across multiple Stack Exchange sites) is not allowed. Please select the community that is best suited to your question. If you want multiple points of view from different communities, you need to edit your question in a way that reflects that.

Hi, I'm new to this Stack Exchange. Would you advise me to post here or on SO ?

I'd say it depends on what your overall goal is & who you want to hear from. Why are you trying to a UE5 GPU Buffer in a CUDA kernel? SO has significantly more users & more posts tagged with UE & Cuda. GDSE has less traffic with a concentration on game dev expertise. If you're trying to do a game dev thing, GDSE makes sense. If not, statistically, SO might be better.

I've put this question on hold for now. It can be re-opened if the duplicate on SO is closed or deleted, or if this version is edited to substantially differentiate it from the version on SO. This helps avoid fragmenting useful information across multiple sites: we want to keep the best answers together on one page so they're easier to compare and contrast, and avoid leaving dead ends for future searches.
